# What are the possible consequences of leaving a phone on at all times?

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy A41, and I created an app to send text messages from my server. The app requires the device to be turned on at all times while the app is open. I have a built-in feature that lets the app keeps the device awake, en to prevent screen burning I have an option to toggle on a color switch, which fills the full screen and switches between colors every 60 seconds.

The device will be on for days, and will be plugged in at all times? What could go wrong?

Comment: Which country and provider are you in/with?  Be aware that your licence with your provider for texting may prohibit what you are doing.

Comment: How long do you mean by all the time?

Comment: @Rohit Gupta: it's for personal messages, no business

Comment: @PeymanMohamadpour: for like a week

Comment: If you really want to keep a phone with screen always on simply buy a cheap one with LCD. The LED backlight will work for years. Keeping a phone always on usually also means always powered via USB. The most sever consequence I see is that the battery is blowing up. So the phone case may break or just disassemble itself but usually the battery doesn't go on fire.